# Reputation not tracked correctly after getting a tag wiki edit accepted, just before I hit the 1K threshold

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, reputation

I have just hit the 1k threshold for suggested edits. On the last day (March 12, 2018) I had 5 suggested edits to tag wikis accepted, only three of which earned me reputation. It looks as though the two edits which did *not* earn me reputation were counted in the ranking.

I had 16,613 rep yesterday (March 11, 2018):

[image: my ranking yesterday]

My reputation history says that I earned 20 rep today (March 12, 2018):

[image: reputation history]

...but I have 16,635 rep currently (and it's been this way for the last hour):

[image: my current reputation]

I **know** that the reason behind the reputation change is that I got one of my tag wiki edits accepted (I know this because my edit queue was full before and I could edit a tag wiki immediately after getting that reputation). I didn't get a notification from this rep change.

I did not receive points for my edits after that, that means this was my last edit that earned me points.

What happened here?

Comment: From your [rep page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3151675/the4kman?tab=reputation&sort=time), it seems to be added to yesterday's count (the edits must have been approved then). Unless there was an additional wiki edit accepted?

Comment: @SurajRao Nope - according to [my reputation history on SE](https://stackexchange.com/users/3796905/the4kman?tab=reputation), I received 31 rep between the day before yesterday and yesterday.

Comment: I've edited a summary in, now we've gone past the day in question can you include actual dates rather than relative ones so that people can see what you mean?

Comment: @Ben Thank you for the edit. I added absolute dates.